# @font-face will not apply any font to page

Tags: css, font-face, truetype, font-family, woff

I have tried both ttf and woff formats with multiple different fonts across chrome, firefox, and edge but it doesn't seem to apply any font no matter what i do. Everything else in the style sheet is referenced perfectly fine besides @font-face. I've checked directory and syntax error but as far as i can see there are none.

.

.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: #B0C1B4;
}

p {
    font-family: font !important;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#log {
    width: 65%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url(data/fonts/font.ttf) format(ttf),
         url(data/fonts/font.woff) format(woff);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the wrong path here.
Path must be like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url(data/fonts/font.ttf) format(ttf),
         url(data/fonts/font.woff) format(woff);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and just directly copy and pasted your reply but unfortunately this does not seem to have changed anything. I also tried referencing classes and ids instead of just a tag set but this doesn't seem to have done anything either.

Comment: Does your font file exists under `data/fonts/` and what is the name of your font?

Comment: You can also check if the font is loaded from browser console

Comment: it does exist under data/fonts as font.ttf and font.woff, I tried to make it as simple as possible for the name to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: Just check whether this font is overrided by some other font-family described in any other stylesheet or inline stye ?

Comment: I do in fact have a second style sheet but I've also tried disabling it (purposeful wrong syntax) to avoid conflict. The issue did seem to exist before i even implemented the 2nd style sheet originally, i was planning to come back to the issue at that time.

I updated the post to show the full 1st style sheet as it currently is.

Comment: Can you try this once `p {
    font-family: font !important;
    font-weight: 100;
}`

Comment: If this doesnot fix your issue, then please create a codepen demo, so i can help you to fix this issue correctly

Comment: It does not seem to have fixed the issue, i'm creating a codepen